# Blazor API Post Not Getting Called

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I am fairly new to Blazor, I am trying to call a Post action in a HandleValidSubmit method of a form.

EditForm Model="@date" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit"

```
private DateGenerator.Shared.Date date = new Date();

[Parameter]
public EventCallback OnSubmitCallback { get; set; }

public async void HandleValidSubmit()
{
    var connectedUser = DateGenerator.Shared.ConnectedUser.Get();
    if (connectedUser == null || connectedUser.UserId == 0)
    {
        string? email = AuthProvider?.GetAuthenticationStateAsync()?.Result?.User?.Identity?.Name;
        if (email == null)
            StateHasChanged();

        var users = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<DateGenerator.Shared.User[]>("api/Users");
        if (users != null && users.Any(u => u.Email == email))
            DateGenerator.Shared.ConnectedUser.Set(users.First(u => u.Email == email));

        connectedUser = DateGenerator.Shared.ConnectedUser.Get();
    }

    if (connectedUser == null)
        return;

    var newDate = new Date(date, connectedUser);

    await Http.PostAsJsonAsync<DateGenerator.Shared.Date>("api/Dates", newDate);
    await OnSubmitCallback.InvokeAsync();

    date.Clear();
}
```

The post in the api controller is not getting called

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class DatesController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly DateGeneratorContext _context;

    public DatesController(DateGeneratorContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<DateGenerator.Shared.Date> Get()
    {
        return _context.Dates.ToList();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public void Post(Shared.Date date)
    {
        _context.Dates.Add(date);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I can call the "Get" function from the same codeblock and it works, and I can't see any difference between this call and ones for other api controllers that work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: And you sure, it gets to that line of code? (I suspect it's 5th from the bottom). Do you see that call in F12?

Comment: It definitely gets to the "PostAsJsonAsync" portion of the "HandleValidSubmit" method, but doesn't enter the "Post" method in the controller.
I get this in the output window:
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.DateGenerator.ServerAPI.ClientHandler[101]
      Received HTTP response headers after 40.7999ms - 400
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.DateGenerator.ServerAPI.LogicalHandler[101]
      End processing HTTP request after 42.3ms - 400

Comment: I'm no expert on API stuff, but 400 suggests a bad request error.  Is `Shared.Date` serializable?  Try this `public void Post([FromBody] Shared.Date date)`.

Comment: Ok, so 400. Have you got swagger in that project? Can you POST from there and compare the requests?

Comment: I figured out what the issue was. There was a null property in the "Shared.Date" that I was trying to post that caused the post to fail.

Comment: Just a side note here: You can make HandleValidSubmit an async Task instead of an async void.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A null property in the object that was being posted caused the post to fail. Make sure all properties that are not nullable have a value.